# Angular + MVC or Vue + MVC?

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, vue.js

Considering a new web solution using MVC with the purpose of displaying real data, will be advisable to combine Vue.js or Angular. Witch of these will work better in a MVC project? I would like to make my choice based in scalability and integration ease with C#.

Comment: Do you want to enjoy development? Vue.js. Do you want to use an enterprise quality (TM) framework where you can find developers for more easily? Use angular.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Angular 4.

I worked with angularJS, Angular 1.6, Angular 2 and Angular 4. I would recommend going with the latter.

angularJS, Angular 1.6 both support two-way data-binding. While Angular >= 2.x doesn’t support the old (built-in) two-way data binding anymore. It supports one way data binding by default, but of course you can activate two-way data binding.

Development with Angular 4 is so interesting and nice once you get to know it. The framework provides interesting way of programming, I recommend you start from these two websites:

[Angular 4 official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

[Angular 4 application development with Bootstrap 4 and TypeScript](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/1366/angular-4-app-typescript-bootstrap)

I also recommend you to develop with [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/). It makes your life easier :)